# How to retrieve list of songs from device using recycler adapter over a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-contentresolver

I want to retrieve list of songs on a device using recycler adapter over Song Fragment. Content resolver implemented to retrieve list of songs is getting error.
Please help

This is what i have done.

- I have created Song model
- Extended 3 fragments(Below is one of Song Fragment) from Main activity

**My SongFragment**

```
public class TabSong extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_song, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    SongList();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}

public void SongList() {
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };

    Cursor cur = cr.query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            sortOrder);

    RecyclerAdapter.songs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  /*  songs.add(cur.getString(0) + "||"
            + cur.getString(1) + "||"
            + cur.getString(2) + "||"
            + cur.getString(3) + "||"
            + cur.getString(4) + "||" );*/

        map.put("ID", cur.getString(0));
        map.put("artist", cur.getString(1));
        map.put("title", cur.getString(2));
        map.put("displayname", cur.getString(3));
        map.put("duration", cur.getString(4));

        RecyclerAdapter.songs.add(map);
    }
}}
```

**My RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{ 

static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songs = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.song_list, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(songs.get(position).get("displayname"));
    holder.artist.setText(songs.get(position).get("artist"));
    holder.duration.setText(songs.get(position).get("duration"));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title,duration,artist;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_artist);
        duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_duration);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**#1**: Don't use a static member to store songs in the adapter. All you need is a `List` of some class that you can define to hold all your song data.

```
public class Song {
    String displayName;
    String artist;
    // etc.
}
```

Make a method in your adapter to swap in the new `List` whenever it gets loaded. Speaking of which...

**#2**: You should be using a `Loader` to load the songs. There is a guide on Loaders [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). The way you do it now is querying the MediaProvider on the UI thread and processing the result also on the UI thread, which is bad. Also, `Loader`s can automatically reload if the data changes, which means you don't have to manually refresh.

You can use a basic `CursorLoader` to start, although you would still be processing the results on the main thread inside of `onLoadFinished()`. If you want to do this better, you can make a custom `Loader` that does the query and also processes the result all in the background, and then publishes the final data structure.

Also, make sure you **close the `Cursor`** when you are done with it.

**#3**: After you add, remove, or change items backing your adapter, you need to call one of the `notify...` methods on the adapter (see the docs starting [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())) so that `RecyclerView` will show the updated data.

Comment: Thankyou @Karakuri . 1 important question, can you explain in brief. How do i connect all (Song Fragment, Recycler adapter, Loader and Model) to the Main Activity where only onCreate method lies. Also Where do i declare and instantiate the Hashmap Array list in the above mentioned classes.

Comment: I would not use a list of `Hashmap`s. If you're extracting the data from the `Cursor` anyway, extract it into something with direct access like the `Song` model class example above. Your adapter can simply have a `List<Song>` that you set via a method call. The Activity should get the `RecyclerView`, initialize the adapter, and start the loader in `onCreate()`. You will get the loaded data in `onLoadFinished()` of your `LoaderCallbacks` you passed to `initLoader()`. In there you convert to a list of songs and pass it to the adapter, which replaces its list and does the notify.